# Angular 2 factory provider

Tags: angular, typescript, auth0

If I create a file like this (auth.module.ts):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { AuthHttp, AuthConfig } from 'angular2-jwt';

export function authHttpServiceFactory(http: Http, options: RequestOptions) {
  return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig(), http, options);
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AuthHttp,
      useFactory: authHttpServiceFactory,
      deps: [Http, RequestOptions]
    }
  ]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

And declare / import it in app.module.ts

```
import {AuthModule} from "./services/auth.module";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ...
    AuthModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

How would I get at the AuthHttp provider from my services?

Thanks!

(more context if needed [here](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/issues/294))

Comment: Just inject it (in the constructor).

Comment: @peeskillet if I do that I get an error in VSC `[ts] Cannot find name 'AuthHttp'.` I tried this: `constructor(private authHttp: AuthHttp) {}`

Comment: Did you import it into the file `import { AuthHttp } from 'angular2-jwt'`?

Comment: @peeskillet I did at the top of my service, I get `No provider for AuthHttp!`.

Comment: A u using th latest cli? There was an issues with early versions of CLI browser not kicking off the code changes.

Comment: @Kuncevic I initially thought the same but it's definitely seeing the code changes